# Python. Выуживание числа из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, list

Я совсем зелёный.

Мне нужно вытянуть конкретные `member_id` из списка и вписать их в переменную, создав свой список из подряд идущих `member_id`.

Вот что я получаю, а из этого мне нужны только числа из `member_id`:

```json
{
  "response": {
    "items": [{
      "member_id": 489569031,
      "join_date": 1544905304,
      "invited_by": 489569031,
      "is_owner": true,
      "is_admin": true
    }, { 
      "member_id": 344648652,
      "join_date": 1531169722,
      "invited_by": 489569031,
      "can_kick": true
    }, {
      "member_id": 381682064,
      "join_date": 1532985294,
      "invited_by": 489569031,
      "can_kick": true
    }, {
      "member_id": 419089414,
      "join_date": 1535742950,
      "invited_by": 489569031,
      "can_kick": true
    },
```

То есть, что бы из этого вышло вроде:

`489569031,344648652,381682064,419089414`

Comment: Код скрином - это жесть

Comment: Свои наработки есть? Или хочешь, чтобы мы за тебя сделали то, что нужно тебе? Будешь так поступать, так и останешься зеленым навсегда.

Comment: Ну чего вы такие суровые
"response": { 
"items": [{ 
"member_id": 489569031, 
"join_date": 1544905304, 
"invited_by": 489569031, 
"is_owner": true, 
"is_admin": true 
}, { 
"member_id": 344648652, 
"join_date": 1531169722, 
"invited_by": 489569031, 
"can_kick": true 
}, { 
"member_id": 381682064, 
"join_date": 1532985294, 
"invited_by": 489569031, 
"can_kick": true 
}, { 
"member_id": 419089414, 
"join_date": 1535742950, 
"invited_by": 489569031, 
"can_kick": true 
},

Comment: @WestSide вы можете править свой вопрос. Замените скриншот на код в текстовом виде непосредственно в вопросе. Дело не в суровости, а в том, что вам могут захотеть помочь, а для этого нужно иметь возможность воспроизвести ваш код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
src = {
  'response': {
    'items': [
      { 'member_id': 123456 },
      { 'member_id': 123457 },
    ]
  }
}    
ids = [item['member_id'] for item in src['response']['items']]
```

Comment: Добавьте тогда еще `print(ids)` и `print(','.join(map(str, ids)))`

Comment: Я ТЕБЯ ОБОЖАЮ БОЖЕ ОЛЕГ И gli9tred Я ВАС ОЧЕНЬ ЛЮБЛЮ ВЫ АМЫЕ КРУТЫЕЕЕЕ


БОЖЕ ХРАНИ ПИТОН И ВАС